# PyQt4: Sending a custom signal from a thread to a progress dialog

Tags: signals, pyqt4

I am unable to send a signal updating a progress dialog from a QThread.
I set up the thing like this (from within the MainWindow class):

```
self.progressDialog = QtGui.QProgressDialog("Packing ...", QtCore.QString(), 0,100, self.parent_)
self.thread = QtCore.QThread(parent = self.parent_)
self.thread.run = myRun
self.thread.start()
self.thread.QtCore.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"), self.progressDialog, QtCore.SLOT("setProgress(int progress, int totalSteps)"))
```

then, from within the myRun function, I try to emit the signal:

```
self.thread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"),progress,total)
```

But the progress dialog just does not update :(.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 1):

I would do something so:

```
self.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("progressUpdated"), self.updateProgress)
```

and then a method (slot) in the mainwindow:

```
  def updateProgress(self, progress):
    self.ui.progressBar.setValue(progress) 
    self.ui.progressBar.repaint()
```

self or self.ui depends if u have subclassed the mainWindow and then launched setupUi

```
self.thread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("updateProgress"),progress)
```

seems correct to me